# how to add authentication information in url using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to provides authentication information such as user name and password in URL to access a REST API using angularjs. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

@Radhika,

You can use token-based authentication system if your end client is mobile/web. If you need this implementation only for web then you can also utilized session/cookies stuff.

You have not shared about your backend technology so I'm just giving reference link (with node)where you can check angualr stuff.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543

Comment: Even you can get lots of example on this stuff when you googling your actual requirement. :P

Comment: I am also using token based authentication system for my mobile application.

Comment: @ manish trivedi,I am trying to use softlayer rest api.and they want  authentication information in url itself.

Answer (score 0):

In a `.config` block, you can set default parameters for $httpProvider that future $http objects will use. [Docs for $httpProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider)

There, you could register an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) to modify the url with the auth details.

edit: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest softlayer API does indeed require auth details in the URL.

Comment: please suggest another way

Comment: You wrote an interceptor already and it didn't work? As in, the url wasn't changed?

Comment: no I did not  wrote interceptor.i mentioned username and apikey in url in $http.get()method,but it not working